# Entity Framework, Link tables and mapping multiple tables to a single entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have an Entity called "Product", this entity, through table mapping, merges 6 tables  that have a 1 to 1..0 relationship with "Products". This all works wonderfully. There is another property I want to add to "Products", which is sBBR_rate, this value is not in a table that has a direct 1 to 1..0 relationship, it is related through a link table as below:

[image: SQL server diagram]

When I import the two tables into the EDM, I can't see a way in the "Mapping Details" of 
"Product" to reference the sBBR_rate. I can reference RatesLink and link that to the "Products" primary key, however, I cannot reference the BBR table.

[image: EDM]

The methods I can think of to work "around" this is are as follows:

- Create a view, reference the view in the EDM.
- Create an SP and use a function import to retrieve the BBR when it is required.
- Create a "Rates" entity in the EDM that can then draw down the sBBR_rate into it. Navigate to the Products BBR through Product.Rates.sBBR_rate.

Is there a better way I can do this that doesn't feel so much like a fudge? Perhaps by directly editing the XML of the Mapping or Conceptual layers of the EDM?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: By looking at your database diagram the simple answer is not possible through mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a view and then linking this view in the EDM, this worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

Because the multiplicities on the `Product` -> `RatesLink` and `RatesLink` -> `BBR` relationships are 0 to 1, you should be able to access the sBBR_rate from a `Product` instance like this:

```
myProductInstance.RatesLink.BBR.sBBR_rate
```

I can see on the EDM screenshot that `RatesLink` has a `Product` and `BBR` property, which would indicate this should be available - is it?

On a side note, if it makes sense for the `sBBR_rate` property to commonly be accessed directly from `Product`, you might want to follow the [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and create a property on `Product` which returns it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And yes, you are correct, I want "sBBR_rate" as a property directly on "Product", however, in the EDM I want to map the table field directly into the "Product" Entity (such as the other six tables are; for instance, there is a MaxLoan table, this is deleted from the EDM as it is mapped directly into the Product entity). If at all possible, I would like to delete the entity "RatesLink" & the entity "BBR" from the EDM, these are not Objects, they are database tables & as I am trying to be tyrannically purist with this first EF project, I would prefer them not to remain.

Answer (score 2):

The model we are using is to extend entities by using partial classes which we've found useful so we can get additional properties in the autogenerated classes (we are using a POCO T4 template to autogen but I believe this would work just as well with the default entity object generation).

So we would have

```
//.. this one is from the T4 template
public partial class Product
{
    //.. all the autogenerated methods
}
```

and in a separate file that isn't autogened

```
//.. now in a separate file created by me
public partial class Product
{
   //.. my custom properties and methods to make the entities more usable
   public string BBRRate
   {
     get {return this.RatesLink.BBR.sBBR_rate; } 
   }
}
```

This means that I can just do

```
myProduct.BBRRte
```

I know there are other ways to do this by amending the edmx file but this one we found easy to implement. You just need to watch performance because you are potentially loading extra data. Also we did this with LazyLoading turned on but with more work you wouldn't have to

We also experimented with hooking into the `ObjectMaterialized` event in the ObjectContext class to preload some of these properties. Using a custom interface i.e. `IMaterialisable` we could check if the object was of that type then call a method (`Materialise`) to prepopulate some of the properties. This seems like a good idea but we didn't widely use it - it was easy to load up too much stuff. If you do the load on the properties in the partial classes then it becomes more efficient. Just my experience.

Anyway - as always an interesting question and good luck again with your dev.

**EDIT**

There is a rule that everything in the store layer must be represented some way in your conceptual layer. Therefore removing the tables from the conceptual layer but bring through some of the properties I don't think will work in it's gross form. Therefore I can think of two further options

1. Create a View on the database and bring that in as you have already mentioned. TBH this is what I would do.
2. Use the [DefiningQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982038.aspx) element directly in your xml (the store layer) and map the query through to a custom entity of your exact design. [Julie Lerman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260) describes this as the ultimate escape hatch for Entity Framework.

Remember though - if you manual amend the XML in point 2 then you lose the ability to automatically update the module through the IDE

Comment: Hello again Crab Bucket, I need to start paying you consultancy :). Thanks for your help. As I added to Steves post above, if at all possible, I would like to delete the entity "RatesLink" & the entity "BBR" from the EDM, these are not Objects, they are database tables so I would prefer them not to remain. I found with the ObjectMaterialized event, it will not fire if you project into a custom or anonymous type, Viz, using "from c in ctx.cars where c.wheels == 4 select new carViewModel {ID = c.ID, Trunk = c.Boot}" will not fire it, "select c" will, so I backed off using it.

Comment: @MagicalArmchair. fair enough with the objectcontext - we didn't find that much use for it but I always thought it looked neat. I've added a couple more thoughts. No probs for the help - it's all two way really

Comment: It works really well if you are materialising whole entities (I was using it for those calculations in earlier posts before I switched to ViewModels), shame it doesn't fire on projection! I have played with a DB View and that might be the answer, I guess that stops me updating through EDM generated code (as a View is immutable), however, I could make Updates, Deletes and Inserts happen through SPs, then that is the problems solved.

Comment: @MagicalArmchair. It is interesting about Materialise not firing on projection - i guess when you think about it it shouldn't as the entity hasn't materialise. I didn't realise it. I have to say I would go with the DB View. We used them quite a bit. I think that the defining query is more for when people don't have control over their databases and can't just bang in a View - a common scenario in a lot of dev shops